# Probability of A or B, given the counts of each category

Tags: probability, statistics

Based on the data below, what is the probability that a person selected at random is Female or drives a Honda?

```
Car    Male  Female Total

Jeep    19    5     24
Toyota  16    30    46
Honda   32    48    80
Total   67    83    150
```

#### Progress

I have divided 83 by 150 to get females and I have divided 80 by 150 to get the number of people who drive hondas. I do not know what to do from there for I keep getting weird answers.

Comment: I have divided 83 by 150 to get females and I have divided 80 by 150 to get the number of people who drive hondas. I do not know what to do from there for I keep getting weird answers.

Comment: What is the probability that a person selected at random is able to understand your question?

Comment: Sorry when I posted it, it looked good.

Comment: Whoever did that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events "Female" (F) and "Honda" (H) are intersecting.

Thus $P(F \cup H)=P(F)+P(H)-P(F \cap H)$ and $P(F \cap H)=\frac{48}{150}$

$P(F)$ and $P(H)$ you have already calculated.

Comment: I tried that but it said that was not the correct answer. Would it not be higher since females are more than 50% and so are hondas?

Comment: What is the correct answer ? The second sentence I do not understand.

Comment: .3200 is the answer correct?

Comment: Than the question has to be: "What is the probability that a person selected at random is Female $\color{red}{\text{AND}}$ drives a Honda "? This is $P(F \cap H)=\frac{48}{150}=0.32$

Comment: Ohhh wait, so basically I take the two I got originally and then subtract the intersection?

Comment: Yes, if you want to calculate the probability, that a person selected at random is female or/and drives a Honda.

Comment: .76666? is what I have now.

Comment: This is correct.